# jQuery URL parser plugin fails on '@' in query string - What URL parsing regex will work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, url, jquery-plugins

**Background**

I use the jQuery [URL parser plugin](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) by [Mark Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76238/mark-perkins) for extracting query string values from the current URL.

The parsing process fails when query string values contain the '@' character, most notably when there is an email address in the query string. This is in reference to the latest version of the plugin, taken from the [github project page](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/) today.

**Working and non-working examples**

The parsing process populates the internal `parsed.queryKey` object with key:value pairs from the query string.

Two modes are offered: 'loose' and 'strict'. Both return the same result.

```
// Parse URL that works
jQuery.url.setUrl("http://example.com/?email=example.example.com");

// Examine result
parsed.queryKey = {
    'email':'example.example.com'
}


// Parse URL that fails
jQuery.url.setUrl("http://example.com/?email=example@example.com");

// Examine result
parsed.queryKey = {
}
```

**Problem**

I'd like to be able to modify one (or both) regular expressions to overcome the issue of the parsing of query string arguments failing when there is an '@' present.

The parser uses regular expressions to extract information from the URL. These are defined on (what is currently) [line 27](http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/blob/master/jquery.url.js#L27):

```
parser: {
    strict: /^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/, //less intuitive, more accurate to the specs
    loose: /^(?:(?![^:@]+:[^:@\/]*@)([^:\/?#.]+):)?(?:\/\/)?((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?)(((\/(?:[^?#](?![^?#\/]*\.[^?#\/.]+(?:[?#]|$)))*\/?)?([^?#\/]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/ // more intuitive, fails on relative paths and deviates from specs
}
```

I don't sufficiently understand the workings of these regular expressions to be able to make the required modifications.

How can I modify the regular expressions to allow the parsing process to work when the is an '@' present in the query string?

Comment: You can't have a `@` in a query string, it's not valid...I'd solve the root issue, how'd it get there? :)

Comment: @Nick, I agree that it's best to HtmlEncode the query string, but who says it's invalid?

Comment: @Brad - `@` is specifically for the user info portion of the URI, it needs to be encoded elsewhere unless it's in a `mailto:`.

Comment: @Nick Craver: I agree that the @ character needs to be encoded to be technically valid. That said, I can't guarantee that the page URL contains correctly-encoded values. Furthermore, the valid placement of an @ character is way before the query string and, whilst it may be technically invalid to place it in the query string, it should be possible to detect. It would be great to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent`

```
var url = "http://example.com/?email=";
var email = encodeURIComponent("example@example.com");
jQuery.url.setUrl(url + email);
```

This will replace @ with %40.

enjoy!

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I can't guarantee correctly-encoded query string values (users can mess with the URL!). Secondly, validly encoding an @ still fails.

Comment: I don't follow.  Can you explain what you are trying to do?  Maybe you are needing `decodeURIComponent` instead?

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Using **[Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/)** I stepped through and can make this suggestive expression:

```
^(?:(?![^:@]+:[^:@\/]*@)([^:\/?#.]+):)?(?:\/\/)?((?:(([^:]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?)(((\/(?:[^?#](?![^?#\/]*\.[^?#\/.]+(?:[?#]|$)))*\/?)?([^?#\/]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)
```

another attempt:

```
^(?:(?![^:@]+:[^:@\/]*@)([^:\/?#.]+):)?(?:\/\/)?((?:(([^:]*):?([^:]*))?)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?)(((\/(?:[^?#](?![^?#\/]*\.[^?#\/.]+(?:[?#]|$)))*\/?)?([^?#\/]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)
```

---

Maybe this RegEx can be of use to you:

```
(?<protocol>(http|ftp|https|ftps):\/\/)?(?<site>[\w\-_\.]+\.(?<tld>([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(aero|arpa|asia|coop|info|jobs|mobi|museum|name|travel))+(?<port>:[0-9]+)?\/?)((?<resource>[\w\-\.,@^%:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@^%/~\+#])(?<queryString>(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\-\._+%\$#\~',/]*=[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\-\._+%\$#\~',/]*)+(&[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\-\._+%\$#\~',/]*=[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\-\._+%\$#\~',/]*)*)?)?
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a useful regex for parsing URLs, but is it a drop-in replacement that works in the context of the given jQuery plugin?

Comment: @Jon, I doubt it's a drop-in replacement and I haven't used the plug-in you're referring to. I just wanted to drop you a suggestion that might be helpful even if it does take a bit more work.

Comment: @Jon, try the updates I made to my answer. I believe I edited the "loose" expression.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll give them a run through and see what they do!